# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'data') in my cartActions.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, axios

I am trying to load a users' cart upon authentication using axios in my react app but it returns an error saying "cannot read properties of undefined(reading 'data')". The error highlights my cartAction.js:15 which is a .catch method that returns the error response data and status but when i console.log the response from my axios.get(`/api/cart/${id}`) it logs the response successfully in my console but it doesn't render in my react app. I think the problem is from my Cart.js component code but i can't seem to rectify it. The console.log(err) in my cartAction.js getCart constant printed "*Error: Checkout(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null.*" in my console

**Here is my cartAction.js code**

```
> export const getCart = (id) => dispatch => {
>     dispatch(setCartLoading());
>     axios.get(`/api/cart/${id}`)
>          .then(res => dispatch({
>              type: GET_CART,
>              payload: res.data
>          })
>          )
>          .catch(err => { 
>              console.log(err) 
>              dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))}); }
> 
> export const addToCart = (id, productId, quantity) => dispatch => {
>     axios.post(`/api/cart/${id}`, {productId, quantity})
>          .then(res => dispatch({
>              type: ADD_TO_CART,
>              payload: res.data
>          }))
>          .catch(err => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))); }
> 
> export const deleteFromCart = (userId, itemId) => dispatch => {
>     axios.delete(`/api/cart/${userId}/${itemId}`)
>     .then(res => dispatch({
>         type: DELETE_FROM_CART,
>         payload: res.data
>     }))
>     .catch(err => dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))); }
> 
> export const setCartLoading = () => {
>     return{
>         type: CART_LOADING
>     } }
```

**Here is my component/Cart.js code**

```
class Cart extends Component{
     state = {
         loaded: false
     }

    static propTypes = {
        getCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        isAuthenticated: PropTypes.bool,
        addToCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        deleteFromCart: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
        user: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        cart: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
        checkout: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    }


     getCartItems = async (id) => {
         await this.props.getCart(id);
         this.state.loaded = true;
     }

     onDeleteFromCart = (id, itemId) => {
         this.props.deleteFromCart(id, itemId);
     }

     render(){
         const user = this.props.user;
         if(this.props.isAuthenticated && !this.props.cart.loading && !this.state.loaded){
             this.getCartItems(user._id);
         }
         return(
             <div>
                 <AppNavbar/>
                 {this.props.isAuthenticated ?
                   <Fragment>
                       { this.props.cart.cart ? null :
                          <Alert className="text-center" color="info">Your cart is empty!</Alert>
                       }
                   </Fragment>
                   : <Alert className="text-center" color="danger">Login to View</Alert> 
                }

                {this.props.isAuthenticated && !this.props.cart.loading && this.state.loaded && this.props.cart.cart ?
                <Container>
                    <div className="row">
                        {this.props.cart.cart.items.map((item)=>(
                            <div className="col-md-4">
                                <Card>
                                    <CardBody>
                                        <CardTitle tag="h5">{item.name}</CardTitle>
                                        <CardSubtitle>NGN {item.price}</CardSubtitle>
                                        <CardText>Quantity - {item.quantity}</CardText>
                                        <Button color="danger" onClick={this.onDeleteFromCart.bind(this, user._id, item.productId)}>Delete</Button>
                                    </CardBody>
                                </Card>
                                <br/>
                            </div>
                        ))}
                        <div className="col-md-12">
                           <Card>
                               <CardBody>
                                   <CardTitle tag="h5">Total Cost = NGN. {this.props.cart.cart.bill}</CardTitle>
                                   <Checkout
                                   user={user._id}
                                   amount={this.props.cart.cart.bill}
                                   checkout={this.props.checkout}
                                   />
                               </CardBody>
                           </Card>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </Container>
                : null
                }
             </div>
         );
     }
 }

 const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
     cart: state.cart,
     isAuthenticated: state.auth.isAuthenticated,
     user: state.auth.user
 })

 export default connect(mapStateToProps, {getCart, deleteFromCart, checkout})(Cart);
```

**Here's my cartReducer.js code**

```
const initialState = {
     cart: null,
     loading: false
 }

export default function cartReducer (state=initialState, action){
     switch(action.type){
         case GET_CART:
             return {
                 ...state,
                 cart: action.payload,
                 loading: false
             }

             case ADD_TO_CART:
                 return {
                     ...state,
                     cart: action.payload
                 }

            case DELETE_FROM_CART: 
                 return {
                     ...state,
                     cart: action.payload
                 }

            case CART_LOADING: 
                 return {
                     ...state,
                     loading: true
                 }

            default: 
            return state;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I don't see where you access any `*.data` property in your UI code, but you do in several places in your action creators in `cartAction` file. Which line is line 15? My guess is that the error object doesn't have the properties you are accessing into, i.e. `err.response` is undefined. Can you update your question to include the result of `console.log(err)`?

Comment: i've updated it with the console.log(err) result

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the issue now. You are issuing a side-effect from your `render` method. `render` is to be considered a synchronous, pure function. If you need to fetch data it should be in one of the component lifecycle methods, i.e. `componentDidMount` and/or `componentDidUpdate`.

Move the "getCartItems" conditional logic into a utility function and invoke from the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method.

```
fetchCartItems = () => {
  const { cart, isAuthenticated, user } = this.props;
  const { loaded } = this.state;

  if (isAuthenticated && !cart.loading && !loaded) {
    this.getCartItems(user._id);
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  this.fetchCartItems();
}

...

render() {
  const { user } = this.props;

  return (
    <div>
      ...
    </div>
  );
}
```

And if there's a chance you may need to again fetch the cart items later *after* the component has mounted, for example, the authentication status changes, use the `componentDidUpdate` method.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
  this.fetchCartItems();
}
```

Comment: I did this and thankfully I didn't get the error again but now when I add items to my cart and load my cart it always respond with the "Your cart is empty" alert. Also when I moved the getCartItems conditional logic from the render method into the utility function I had to change the user._id to this.props.user_id or else it user becomes undefined

Comment: @Fransco You may want to wait to render the empty cart alert until you've loaded the state fully, i.e. wait until `this.state.loaded` is true.

Comment: I tried this but my cart still shows up empty

Comment: @Fransco I don't know what your redux state looks like, but are you sure your cart is populated? Can you add your reducer code to your question? And if possible think you could create a *running* codesandbox example of your code we can inspect and debug live?

Comment: I've updated the question to include my cart reducer code

Comment: @Fransco From what I can tell, you would only see the "Your cart is empty" alert if `this.props.cart.cart` is falsey, and the only way I see that is with the initial cart state, or if the `action.payload` in the reducer updates `cart` to be falsey. Have you tried `!this.props.cart.cart && this.state.loaded && <Alert .....`? Outside of this it's difficult to say why the alert is rendered without seeing the state and redux state values *at that time*.

Comment: I don't know if it is possible to upload the frontend and backend of my code on codesandbox.io for us to debug it live. I also get this warning in my console "Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `addToCart` is marked as required in `Cart`, but its value is `undefined`." if this gives a hint to fix the bug. Thanks very much for the help so far, i really appreciate it

Comment: @Fransco You can recreate with your front end code and just mock the data that would be fetched. As for `addToCart`, yes, you made it a required prop in `Cart` but you don't reference it at all. It would normally be added in the `mapDispatchToProps` object passed to the `connect` HOC.